Get token using uniswap V3
I deployed 3 tokens and created a liquidity pool with tokens 1 & 2 then tokens 2 & 3. Now i want to get the token 3 in token 1 using UniswapV3.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Compatible with OpenZeppelin Contracts ^5.0.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Permit.sol";

contract Token1 is ERC20, Ownable, ERC20Permit {
    constructor(address initialOwner)
        ERC20("Token1", "MTK1")
        Ownable(initialOwner)
        ERC20Permit("MyToken")
    {
        mint(initialOwner, 1000000 * 10**18);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}

contract Token2 is ERC20, Ownable, ERC20Permit {
    constructor(address initialOwner)
        ERC20("Token2", "MTK2")
        Ownable(initialOwner)
        ERC20Permit("MyToken")
    {
        mint(initialOwner, 1000000 * 10**18);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}

contract Token3 is ERC20, Ownable, ERC20Permit {
    constructor(address initialOwner)
        ERC20("Token3", "MTK3")
        Ownable(initialOwner)
        ERC20Permit("MyToken")
    {
        mint(initialOwner, 1000000 * 10**18);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}


It is hard to understand what you want to do. Please edit, develop and explain your question.
